# Why do you wonder who was dismissed? (Complementizer position)

Tags: syntax-trees

(sorry about my english, I'm not a native speaker) I'm studying syntactic trees and I'm having huge difficulties understanding the tree of the following sentence: "why do you wonder who was dismissed?"
Why does the position of the complementizer C is empty and not filled with "was"? I really don't understand it. If you would be so kind to help me I'd really appreciate it.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

"who was dismissed" is an embedded question.  It's unembedded form would be "Who was dismissed?", so no complementizer was added to convert the independent form into the embedded form.  I don't understand why "was" would ever be considered a complementizer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've only been studying syntactic trees for a couple of weeks, so I'm still a little bit confused. I thought the C-position should have been filled with the auxiliary which moves from the Inflection position to the complementizer position. If I say "who has arrived?" this movement can be done, "has" raises and fills the complementizer position (at least this is what my lecturer said). Why can't the same movement be done with "was"?    Thank you very much

Comment: I'm not familiar with an analysis where there is a complementizer even though there is no complement (in the independent question "who has arrived?"), and in any case, the position of "has" after the subject is not the position of a complementizer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I make a mistake writing the wrong sentence, the sentence I was referring to was "who has bought this book?" (not who has arrived). Thank you for your explanation

Comment: Due to high production at MIT, theories are always shipped from there with more nodes than they actually need at the moment, so they can be used with new theories that become available in the next months. Pay no attention to empty nodes; they're soluble in oxygen, so they all disappear when the sentence is pronounced.

Comment: Demonstrating @GregLee 's point with Alemannic (aka Swiss German): There you actually do have a complementizer in this configuration, which can be glossed as: "why do you wonder who that was dismissed" (warum wundrasch di wer das usighaut worden ischt)